# Blender 3: boolean modifier works no more on object instance

Tags: modifiers, geometry-nodes

I have a test case taken from another model:

- `white_mesh` is a digitized mesh, it works properly with booleans;
- `white_mesh_scaled` is an empty mesh `union`ed with `white_mesh`; it works properly with booleans if a `fast` modifier is used (looks like a bug in `exact` if one of the arguments is empty, but it is not the subject of this question);
- `black_mesh` uses `Instance on Points` in order to copy and move `white_mesh_scaled`.

Here is the problem: `Point instance` has been obsoleted in Blender 3. Because `black_mesh` did not work properly with booleans in Blender 3 (it did work in Blender 2.93), I replaced the obsoleted node with the new `Instance on Points` in a hope of fixing that:

[image]

The resulting mesh `black_mesh` looks ok but it also does not work with some booleans anymore. In particular, its modifier `Difference` with `black_cut_side` does not change anything.

Of course, the problem may be outside of geometry nodes, because Blender's version changed. Anyway, how to correct for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add **Realize Instances** node before Output ...

[image]

... you can also use **Mesh Boolean** node instead of modifier.

[image]